# How to get a query variable?

Tags: wp-query, query, query-variable

I have added a query variable with the following function:

```
function add_my_query_var() {
    global $wp;
    $wp->add_query_var('myvar1');
}
add_filter('init', 'add_my_query_var');
```

Now on a specific page (author)`example.com/author/admin/myvar1`, `$wp_query` returns:

```
WP_Query Object
(
    [query] => Array
        (
            [author_name] => admin
            [myvar1] => 
        )

    [query_vars] => Array
        (
```

So I can see that the variable is set. However since it is empty, I cannot use following condition to check:

```
if ( get_query_var('myvar1') ) {
    echo "is set";
}
```

What is other way to check if the `myvar1` exists or not? I cannot use `$_GET` because of permalinks.

Edit: Here's the code to rewrite the URL:

```
add_rewrite_rule('author/([^/]+)/myvar1/?$', 'index.php?author_name=$matches[1]&myvar1=$matches[2]', 'top');
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? How are you passing "myvar"? Are you passing it via a rewrite structure? If so, what is that rewrite structure?

Comment: I want to create a custom url on author profile, eg. /author/myvar1 and on the profile page I want to check if there is myvar1 in the url, then display posts using a different query. I have added rewrite rule and everything works fine. now I only want to check if there is myvar1 in the URL or not. I could use $_GET but that would not work because of permalink. Hope it makes sense.

Comment: This isn't very easy to achieve, as WordPress uses a default value for all query vars. Could you post your rewrite structure here? When `myvar1` is filled, e.g. in `example.com/author/jay/somevar`, does `get_query_var( 'myvar1' )` return that value (in this case, "somevar")?

Comment: added code in the question.

Comment: Please answer the second question in my last comment.

Comment: No because its empty, it returns `string(0) ""`. However as I wrote in my question that it is in the `$wp_query`, as you can see the output of `$wp_query` above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably provide different default if empty string is indistinguishable from your value.

```
$myvar = get_query_var( 'myvar1', false );

if ( false !== $myvar ) {

    // stuff
}
```